# str_detect with outside object pattern (in a tidy way ..)

Tags: r, pattern-matching, tidyverse

I would like to optimize my code.

I’m working with `str_detect` to make a lot of selections, as I would like to optimize my code for the future I would like to select, have a *filter pattern* defined, based on an externally defined object. I can do that, but I have to strip my way to the object using `as.character()`. Is it possible to do it in a tidy way?

Working example demonstrating the issue. This is the classical way, it works

```
> tbl %>% mutate(twentys = case_when(
+   str_detect(fruit, "20") ~ T) )
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x fruit        twentys
  <int> <chr>        <lgl>  
1     1 apple 20     TRUE   
2     2 banana 20    TRUE   
3     3 pear 10      NA     
4     4 pineapple 10 NA
```

This is how I imaged I could do, but it doesn’t way

```
> twenty <- 20
> tbl %>% mutate(twentys = case_when(
+   str_detect(fruit, twenty) ~ T) )
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `twentys`.
x no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
i Input `twentys` is `case_when(str_detect(fruit, twenty) ~ T)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

This is the cumbersome way, using `as.character()`, that I would like to optimize.

```
> tbl %>% mutate(twentys = case_when(
+   str_detect(fruit, as.character(twenty)) ~ T) )
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x fruit        twentys
  <int> <chr>        <lgl>  
1     1 apple 20     TRUE   
2     2 banana 20    TRUE   
3     3 pear 10      NA     
4     4 pineapple 10 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` if you don't want to convert `twenty` to character.

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% mutate(twentys = case_when(grepl(twenty, fruit) ~ TRUE))

#  x        fruit twentys
#1 1     apple 20    TRUE
#2 2    banana 20    TRUE
#3 3      pear 10      NA
#4 4 pineapple 10      NA
```

**data**

```
tbl <- structure(list(x = 1:4, fruit = c("apple 20", "banana 20", "pear 10", 
"pineapple 10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
twenty <- 20
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tbl %>%
     mutate(twenty = case_when(str_detect(fruit, str_c(twenty)) ~ TRUE))
```

Or wrap with `paste`

```
tbl %>%
     mutate(twenty = case_when(str_detect(fruit, paste(twenty)) ~ TRUE))
```

#### data

```
tbl <- structure(list(x = 1:4, fruit = c("apple 20", "banana 20", "pear 10", 
 "pineapple 10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
twenty <- 20
```

Comment: Did you see my third option? In that I use `as.character()`. I am looking for something tidier. Hence my question about _code optimization_.

Comment: @EricFail sorry, didn't check it in your question.  I updated with `str_c`

Comment: Thanks. It's different than  `as.character()`, but not much tidier. With Ronak Shah's solution I do not have to wrap my external object at all.

Comment: @EricFail but it is a base R option